# USB drive emulator

Tags: windows-7, usb, duplicate, emulation

My company uses a software that needs an "original" USB drive inserted, but that's an old software, and currently we only have 1 working pen left. Is there any way to create an image of the pen, or something like that so we can have the software on 2 of our PC's?

Comment: Make sure they have the same filesystem and volume label, and then simply copy all the files from the working USB to the other one... Let us know if that works.

Comment: doesn't work, the software works in any folder i place it, but the original usb drive needs to be inserted, even if i put another usb inside ,as FAT and no label, it doesn't work

Comment: There is either a hidden file on the pen drive or the key is sotred in the firmware etc and is enumerated by PnP (etc). It sounds like a hardware security dongle and as such is probably off topic for the site(?)

Comment: There are services that will "hack a dongle" for obsolete unsupported dongle secured software, search for Dongle dupe, duplication, or emulation. The costs of a custom hack can be more than the original software costs, so if it is not obsolete, unsupported, very mission important sofware, dont bother.  Just purchace another dongle, even if that means buying the package one more time, or using a replacement softwares.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is a USB mass storage device and not a security key?

Security keys can be duplicated but it requires intimate knowledge of the controller chip and likely is in violation of any license you're using the software with.

If this is truly a USB flash drive, with no other additional devices (USB devices can present themselves as multiple devices to Windows, so open Device Manager and watch for new devices) - try to find a device of the same exact make and model and use an imaging utility such as [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) or similar to copy it on the sector level.  At the very least try to make sure it's the same capacity.